# how to do post in jquery for localhost url

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I just need to do post with normal Jquery $Post.

> $.post('http:// loc@lhost :8084/restdemo/webresources/employee/1',{ser:ser},function(data)
>   {
>       $('#success').html(data); });

Please suggest me to communicate with this link.

Comment: What's the problem? Did you get the data(ser) in the backend? Did you return something? Lose the "" around data or you'll just have "data" as a string even successful

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({ url: "webresources/employee/1", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", type: "POST",
     data: '{"id":' + id + '}',
     success: function (result) {
         if (result == null || result.d == null) return;
           $('#success').html(result.d); 
});
```

You don't need to paste full url of your local host. Just relative path of the web method location only needed.

Comment: actually, i am running both servers(apache, glassfish). the page apache communicate the page in glassfish, so have to mention all the url